# How to broadcast audio/video online without using flash?

Tags: html, audio, video, broadcast, wowza

I would like to broadcast audio/video directly from a website, without using flash.

I know i should use a broadcast server (i've already found wowza as good server), but my problem is how to send the audio/video coming from the input ( audio,video tags if i'm using html5) to the broadcast server.

(My page language is PHP).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you plan to use as a source?  Your audio/video tags are for the output from your server, not for the input to the server.